# Customized circular checkbox in Android

Tags: android, checkbox, material-design, android-appcompat

I am trying to get the Google apps photo select UI .. Am using Appcompat checkbox to achieve that with out success. The steps I am working on ,
 1. Set the checkbox background to custom circular shape
 2. define custom shape in xml

This is my check box xml looks like ,

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
            android:background="@drawable/checkbox_drawable"
            />
```

My custom checkbox background,

```
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="oval">
    <stroke
       android:width="1dp"
       android:color="#78d9ff"/>
    <solid
    android:color="#79bfea"/>
   </shape>
```

My checkbox button ,

```
<selector>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_drawable"
      android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_check"
      android:state_checked="true"/>
 </selector>
```

I even changed from android:background to android:button .. nothing gives me the circular check box .. Any help is appreciated ? Should I use floating action bar ? or a view ? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 5):

**Custom Checkbox with two drawable image.**

**1.** In **.xml** file

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
   android:id="@+id/checkBox"
   android:layout_width="40dp"
   android:layout_height="40dp"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:background="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
   android:button="@color/white"
   android:checked="true" />
```

**2.** Create **checkbox_selector.xml**  in **drawable** folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/cancel"
       android:state_checked="false"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/checked"
       android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

**3.** Add **checked.png** and **cansel.phd** image in **drawable** folder from the below link

https://icons8.com/icon/set/yes/all

And

https://icons8.com/icon/set/cross/all

**4.** Checkbox **click event**

```
AppCompatCheckBox checkBox = (AppCompatCheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

       if (checkBox.isChecked()){
      checkBox.setChecked(false);
       }else {
         checkBox.setChecked(true);
       }
         }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give size to your drawable when you want to use it for button attribute.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
   <stroke
       android:width="1dp"
       android:color="#78d9ff"/>
   <solid android:color="#79bfea"/>
   <size
       android:width="20dp"
       android:height="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

And apply to CheckBox with `android:button`.

Also since this is a checkbox, you should use selector to have checked and unchecked state.

An example of selector is

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal"
          android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checked"
          android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: I tried this .. all the drawables are greyed out but visible .. only when i click the checked state drawable is displaying correctly. I must be doing some thing wrong.. any idea ?

Comment: Try adding <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_drawable"/> inside of selector block.  This should be for the default state.

Comment: If you would like to update question, please consider adding separation line and additional info under the original question and keep original question texts above.  Now this answer looks mis-matched with the question.

Comment: I used Appcompat checkbox and removed background .. then it worked like expected

Answer (score 0):

You may not be looking now, however i have code which seems to make circular image with checkbox please have a look at my answer given on another thread.

[Click here to view answer on another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42764334/4056108)

Answer (score 0):

**Create a custom checkbox background**
custom_check_box_background.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_unchecked_check_box_background"
            android:state_checked="false"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checked_check_box_background"
            android:state_checked="true"/>
    </selector>
```

After this go to the checkbox and call this xml file from the checkbox

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"                         
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:checked="true"
  android:button="@drawable/custom_check_box_background"                                                                                              
  android:gravity="center" />
```

This will allow you to switch the icons based on the status of checkbox.
Note: You can add your own drawable as background to obtain your desired shape.