# How to create the checkBox in circular shape?

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I am facing the issue in creating the checkbox in circular shape in android. I tried many methods but my problem is not solved.I created the shapes and applied to the checkbox then also problem is not solved.Please help me how to create the check box in circle shape .[image]

How to create the circular checkbox like shown image.

Comment: [similar question] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38798168/customized-circular-checkbox-in-android  Have you tried this?

Comment: I tried that but the problem is not solved

Comment: "problem is not solved" - is not helping.. please - read the similar question, try to do something, post some of your code and try to focus us on the part you think is not working... thank you

Comment: Still the problem is not solved

Comment: Post your code here and if you are getting any errors post that too

Comment: My code working correctly ,my problem is solve the square shaped checkbox into circular checkbox

Comment: for simplicity, if you just want to use circle shape, you can use default android style: `android:drawableEnd="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"`, otherwise create custom drawable as @chirag90 stated

Comment: https://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2019/09/android-rounded-checkbox-vector-drawable.html   Pls check this out, it solved my issue.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

After spending some time, i have created this template, which you can use. **You may need to modify as required**.

In activity.xml

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkb"
    android:layout_width="115dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
    android:scaleX="3"
    android:scaleY="3"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp" />
```

create a new xml in drawable folder called custom_checkbox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/checked" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/checked" />
    <item android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked" />
</selector>
```

create a new xml in drawable folder called checked.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <corners android:radius="1dp" />
                    <stroke
                        android:width="1dp"
                        android:color="#777" />
                    <gradient
                        android:startColor="#990000"
                        android:centerColor="#990000"
                        android:endColor="#990000"
                        android:angle="270" />
                    <size
                        android:width="30dp"
                        android:height="30dp" />
                </shape>
                </item>

            <item
                android:width="8dp"
                android:height="2dp"
                android:top="20dp"
                android:left="6dp">
                <rotate
                    android:fromDegrees="45">
                    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                        <solid android:color="#fff"/>
                    </shape>
                </rotate>
            </item>

            <item
                android:width="19dp"
                android:height="2dp"
                android:top="16dp"
                android:left="9dp">
                <rotate
                    android:fromDegrees="-45">
                    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                        <solid android:color="#fff"/>
                    </shape>
                </rotate>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

</selector>
```

create a new xml in drawable folder called unchecked.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
        <corners android:radius="1dp" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#777" />
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#990000"
            android:centerColor="#990000"
            android:endColor="#990000"
            android:angle="270" />
        <size
            android:width="30dp"
            android:height="30dp" />
    </shape>
```

When unchecked it looks as below. (you can add the code between  from checked.xml and modify the top and left to give X when checkbox is not checked)

[image: unchecked State]

When checked it will look as below

[image: checked state]

If this works mark it as answer.

Comment: Shape comes out all weird on android version 4.4 ... Any suggestions to make it work here? Nice checkbox otherwise :)

Comment: Hi @JayB, I have not looked at the 4.4, I created this in marshmellow 6.0. You could try modifying checked.xml and unchecked.xml

Answer (score 10):

many of the previous answers are well accepted with chirag90's answer being the best but also need a lot of coding, in my answer i will retake his concept but will show you how you can create your own circular checkbox drawables with all the style you want without any coding needed, you will then use this drawables to defind the states of the checkbox like in chirag90's answer

first go to [freelogomaker.com](https://logomakr.com) and create your drawables, it is very easy to use and you can create any thing, on the website go to the shape's search bar and type "round checkbox" then click the search button, a list of mutiple drawables will be presented to you so you can choose

[image: checkbox]

above are the drawables i selected, customise as you wish and save then go to [appiconmaker.co](https://appiconmaker.co) and use the drawables you created to generate the various design sizes of the drawables like mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi and xxhdpi, below are the drawables i made

[image]
unchecked checkbox

[image]
checked checkbox

once that is done you can then add the drawables to your project with the coresponding names checked and unchecked in your drawables folder,once all that done now create custom_checkbox.xml like in chirag90's answer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/checked" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/checked" />
    <item android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked" />
</selector>
```

now in your layout create your checkbox as follows

```
<CheckBox
 android:id="@+id/checkman"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
 android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
 android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
 android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
 android:scaleX="0.8"
 android:scaleY="0.8" />
```

you my then modify the `android:scaleX="0.8"` and `android:scaleY="0.8"` to fit your layout

this is the result in my project

[image]
unchecked

[image]
checked

hope this helps many out there

Answer (score 4):

Solution accepted is correct, but following the same flow you can change the shapes to use a drawable on the "checked.xml" this solution should work with android devices before API 21 because there is no width or height on shapes on xml drawables.

**Unchecked XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">


        <solid android:color = "@color/lightgray" />
</shape>
```

**Checked XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <layer-list xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
                </shape>
                </item>

            <item
                         android:drawable="@drawable/check_arrow_png" />
        </layer-list>
```

Comment: Also the Vector image for the check arrow is Check on android vectors, with that you should have a checkbox with material design style

Comment: this solution is better than other :)

Answer (score 4):

All the answers above require creating custom drawables while we can achieve this by using built-in vector drawables.
Have a look at [this](https://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2019/09/android-rounded-checkbox-vector-drawable.html) post it explains this beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to answer of Rodolfo, I can add, that you can use `inset` attributes if your drawable is too big.
Note: the solution of @chirag90 works only for API 23 and higher.
Note: `vector drawable` can be rendered badly.

**Checked.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid
                android:color="@color/col_chat_selected"/>
            <size
                android:width="35dp"
                android:height="35dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <inset
            android:drawable="@drawable/shape"
            android:insetBottom="10dp"
            android:insetLeft="10dp"
            android:insetRight="10dp"
            android:insetTop="10dp"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

### All the proposed options are sheer nonsense, since it is difficult and not beautiful, my solution: learn vector animation and make everything beautiful with [ShapeShifter.design](https://shapeshifter.design/)

- Create **TWO** animations **Start_to_End** and **End_to_Start**;
- Export the created animation in the format **AnimationVectorDrawable**;
- Move your animation to the resources folder **drawable**;
- Place **ImageView** in **XML**;
- For convenience, create **CustomImageView** { *Do not worry below will be an example* };

  ```
  @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
  class CustomCheckBox(
  context: Context,
  attrs: AttributeSet
  ) : AppCompatImageView(context, attrs) {

  private val TAG = this::class.simpleName

  private val check =
    resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.avd_anim_start_to_end)!!.toAnimationVectorDrawable()
  private val uncheck =
     resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.avd_anim_end_to_start)!!.toAnimationVectorDrawable()

  init {
    setImageDrawable(check)
    setOnClickListener { animateCheckOrUncheck() }
  }

  private fun animateCheckOrUncheck() {
    check.registerAnimationCallback(object : Animatable2.AnimationCallback() {
        override fun onAnimationEnd(drawable: Drawable?) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onAnimationEnd: check")
            check.reset()
            setImageDrawable(uncheck)
        }
    })

    uncheck.registerAnimationCallback(object : Animatable2.AnimationCallback() {
        override fun onAnimationEnd(drawable: Drawable?) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onAnimationEnd: uncheck")
            uncheck.reset()
            setImageDrawable(check)
        }
    })

    (drawable as AnimatedVectorDrawable).start()
   }
  }

  @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
  private fun Drawable.toAnimationVectorDrawable(): AnimatedVectorDrawable {
  return (this as AnimatedVectorDrawable)
  }
  ```